# Does NPOI package use API to Generate excel file?

Tags: c#, api, npoi

I am planning to use NPOI package to generate excel file.(get it from nuget package)
But I am worrying about if the package call api in the backend?

I briefly went thru the github repo. Not seeing they call API.but in the testcase comment it keep mentioning API.So I want to confirm that.
I know that it is a C# version of POI(in java, it is API).

Does anyone know if the package will send the data to API to generate the excel file?
Since I have sensitive data. I don't want my data being sent to API.

Answer (score 1):

No, NPOI doesn't make any backend API calls. Logic is all in the package.